What is the best way to implement file cacheing by different types?
The index page of website I'm working on sends 136 HTTP requests of which 105 are images, which I would like to have cached. The page currently has the meta tags cache-control no-cache and pragma no-cache. I have read a lot of answers on here but it's still not too clear for me.
So, the questions I have are as follows.

If the cacheing is eventually set up on the server, would having the cache-control and pragma tags override the server cache directives - in other words should they be removed?

I've seen some people talking about putting directives in .htaccess and others saying to put it in httpd.conf - which is the better solution?

It seems like using the Last-Modified check is the way to go, so that any files that haven't been modified on the server are just taken from the local browser cache, right? How do I implement this on the server and do I need to change any of the tags in the html pages?

I would like to cache the images, js and css files (with the Last-Modified check in place) but NOT the html pages. How would I set this up on the server?


Thanks for any help you can give!

Please read [ask]. Right now, this is multiple questions in one, and each of your questions are opinion/recommendation-based. There's just no way to provide an objecitve answer to this.
